# Using web workers for multiple concurrent heavy calculations?

Tags: javascript, web, web-worker

I want to do a multiple concurrent heavy calculations that have the same formula. Do I have to create multiple worker files for each or I just need one?

Comment: Why did this get down voted? This is a legitimate question that seems valid per all SO criteria that I can think of. +1

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need multiple files. You can [instantiate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker) multiple workers from the same script file, and then send them different arguments.